Trying to set to drive 32:9 monitor (windows 10). I access Display Adapter Properties and the List All Modes but I get "you do not have authority"
I am trying to set my gaming computer to drive a new 32:9 monitor.  The NVidia GPU is suitable and when I go to Display Adapter Properties and then Display All Modes there are several suitable 32:9 resolutions shown.  But when I select one and try to apply it I get a message "you do not have appropriate authorisation to make this change"...it's my laptop!  Please help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
